# xmlhttprequest status is always 0 and no response in responseText

Tags: node.js, ajax, ionic-framework

I have written a simple node.js server and and ajax request to send and recieve request respectively. Despite of every change made its not working.this is my node.js server code...

```
var express=require('express');
var server=express();
server.get('/sampleResponse',function(req,res){
    if(req.method=="POST"){
        console.log('reache`enter code here`d post');
        res.status(200).send('connection successful');
    }else if(req.method=="GET"){
        console.log('reached get');
        res.status(200).send('connection successful');
    }

});
server.listen('8001','127.0.0.1');
```

//////below is my html page... running on localhost:8100

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>
            function submitLoginDetails(){                
                var JSONLoginObj={rollNo:document.getElementById("rollNo").value,
                                password:document.getElementById("password").value};
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange  = function(){ 
                    var xhrdata = "";
                    if(xhttp.readyState  == 4){
                        if(xhttp.status  == 200) 
                            alert(xhttp.responseText); 
                        else 
                            alert(xhttp.status);
                        }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8001/sampleResponse", false);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ion-pane>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
                <h1 class="title">Login Page</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <form>
                    Roll Number:<br><br>
                    <input type="text" id="rollNo"><br><br>
                    Password:<br><br>
                    <input type="text" id="password"><br><br>
                    <button id="loginButton" onclick="submitLoginDetails();">Login</button>
                </form>
                <p id="demo"></p>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
    </body>
</html>

when access the same page by clicking on link i get response but no response in xhttp.responseText.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cross domain issue (**CORS**) which means you are trying to make a request (for a resource) from outside of your current domain. You need to allow set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to accept all your requests.

You can do this by adding the below lines to your **.js** file (where you have your express.js code)

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot david...... you dont know how much its valuable to me. I had spent hours to make it working.

Comment: can u please give the links to good tutorials on node.js and web development(no html tutorials)...... thanks in advance

Comment: @VineetJain Checkout the resources listed out here => https://github.com/vioan/nodejs-learning-resources